# Find the index of the sub-array that does not contain a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
var array = [[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[2,3,9],[7,8,1]];
var number = 3;
```

If I have this nested array and this variable how do I return the index of the sub-arrays where the number is present. So the final result should be 1 and 3.

Comment: a loop inside another

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example

Comment: Maybe the shortest answer: `array.map((x,i)=>~x.indexOf(number)?i:-1).filter(x=>~x)`

Comment: Really cool answer but it's off by 1

Comment: If the OP means _not contain_, then invert the ternary to: `?-1:i` :p

Comment: @ParvSharma. I didn't get your edit :/

Comment: only if the number "is there" the final result will be 1 and 3 @washington

Comment: @ParvSharma Given both the title and the text said "not contain", are you sure it was a good idea to remove "not"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
array.reduce((acc, subArr, i) => {
  if (!subArr.includes(number)) {
    acc.push(i);  
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `Array.prototype.forEach()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()` functions:

```js
var arr = [[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[2,3,9],[7,8,1]],
    number = 3,
    result = [];
    
arr.forEach(function(v,i){
    if (v.indexOf(number) === -1) result.push(i);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (v.indexOf(number) !== -1) result.push(i + 1);`? " how do I return the index of the sub-arrays where the number is present"

Comment: @instead, the title is *Find the index of the sub-array that does **not** contain a number*

Comment: Oh, that is interesting. Title and description are inconsistent

Comment: @instead, there also "title-supporting" sentence: *So the final result should be 1 and 3*

Answer (score 0):

```
function X(a){
  var r = [];
  for(var i = o ; i < a.length; i++)
    for(var j = o ; j < a[i].length; i++)
        if(a[i][j] === number) 
          r.push(i);
  return r;
}
```

i think this should do it. i have just written it here so might have some syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is super inconsistent, if you want the index of the subarrays that *do* have the number, do this:

```
var foundIndices = [];
for(var y = 0;y < array.length; y++) {
    for(var x = 0;x < array[y].length; x++) {
        if(array[y][x] == number) {
            foundIndices[foundIndices.length] = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, do this:

```
var foundIndices = [];
var found = false;
for(var y = 0;y < array.length; y++) {
    found = false;
    for(var x = 0;x < array[y].length; x++) {
        if(array[y][x] == number) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(found == false) {
        foundIndices[foundIndices.length] = y;
    }
}
```